# How to prevent people with limited user accounts from accessing my computer

Tags: keyboard, passwords

How can I stop limited user of my computer from using the F2 or F12 keys to access my computer while I'm away? They will use them to start it in safe mode and while they are in there it bypasses my password and I don't want them deleting or moving my file around. In fact all I want them to be able to do is go on the internet. They don't need access to any thing else. Can I do that?

Comment: Enable a BIOS password that only you know.  Its not clear how pressing F2 or F12 would bypass your os user's password.

Comment: I think the OP means by entering safe mode since it boots you right into windows without asking for credentials.

Comment: Since when does Safe Mode work without credentials?

Comment: Encrypt the disk. That way they can not modify anything without the right password. Make sure that only the right users have access to the decryption keys (by default this includes admin, but you can remove this account from the group).

Comment: The duplicate linked does not do a good job of addressing the full range of the ops question.

Answer (score 3):

First off, understand that physical access == root access. Period.

as such, there is nothing you can do that will absolutely prevent unauthorized users who have access to the physical pc.

In this regard, traditional security tactics like fences, armed guards, and locked doors are your best means of protection.

for the average home user, the only options left to you are:

1. place a lock on the case, so it cannot be opened.
2. place a password on the BIOS for both management and boot up (to block both F2 and F12).
3. disable the booting of external media, like optical media, usb
   media, and network boot protocols.
4. use disk encryption so the drive cannot be removed and inspected in another machine.